# Based on status in url to assign task in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have this URL (part of the url):
index.php?option=com_umpai&status=success

When status = success is pass to component, i want it to run success task.
So i created a router php file to get status and put in task. Not sure if this is a correct method to do it? How can i put in the task by getting status in my url?

I am wondering does router.php apply to url type in the address bar?

This is my router codes:

```
<?php 

 defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

 function UmpaiBuildRoute(&$query)
{
$segments = array();

if(isset($query['status']))
{
    switch($query['status']) {
        case 'success':
            $segments[] = 'success'; 
        case 'fail':
            $segments[] = 'fail';
        case 'cancel':
            $segments[] = 'cancel';
    }
    $segments[] = $query['task'];
    unset($query['task']);
    unset($query['status']);
}
return $router->build($segments);
}

function UmpaiParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();
   $count = count($segments);
   if(!empty($count)) {
     if($segments[0] == 'success'){
        $vars['task'] = 'success';
        }
  }

   return $router->parse($vars);
  }
```

This is the simple code version to test if my router is working, but it is not working too:

```
 function UmpaiBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();
    $segments[] = 'success';
    return $segments;
}
function UmpaiParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();
    $count = count($segments);
   if(!empty($count)) {
      if($segments[0] == 'success'){
         $vars['task'] = 'success';
     }
}

   return $vars;
   var_dump($vars);
}
```

I tried this as well:

```
function UmpaiBuildRoute(&$query)
{
   $segments[] = $_GET['status'];
}
function UmpaiParseRoute($segments)
{
   $vars = array();
   $count = count($segments);
   if(!empty($count)) {
     if($segments[0] == 'success'){
         $vars['task'] = 'success';
     }
} 

  return $vars;
}
```

Comment: You can grab any variable in the **URL** with the superglobal variable `$_GET` like in this case `$_GET['status']`.

Comment: Hi Varhaeren, in that case, would it be a good practice if i were to do my conditioning in controller.php? @Verhaeren

Answer (score 0):

Verhaeren (in the comments for the question) is right, try this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['status'])) {
  // if status is set:
  switch($_GET['status']) {
    case 'success':
        $segments[] = 'success'; 
    case 'fail':
        $segments[] = 'fail';
    case 'cancel':
        $segments[] = 'cancel';
  }
} else {
  // if status is not set...
};
```

Note: instead of this switch, you could also use `$segments[] = $_GET['status'];`

Comment: @Kimberlee Well, I don't know then. Good luck on your search for knowledge and the right code!

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an array but `$_GET['status']` is a string. `$_GET` is an array with all **URL** variables (if any).

```
function UmpaiParseRoute()
{
   $vars = array();

   if(isset($_GET['status'])) {
        $vars['task'] = 'success';
   }

  return $vars;
}
```

*Also notice you don't need to pass `$_GET` as a parameter because is a **SUPERGLOBAL** variable*.